# Ionic 2 Grid headers not lining up with column data

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic2

Currently I am trying to create a simple list with multiple data fields.  The reason I opted for the grid instead of a simple ion-list is the fact that I have multiple data fields that I would like headers to line up with.  Each row should be a clickable detail that would then take you to another page via a .push() command.  Because of the styling of  being different than either nothing directly after ion-grid or a ion-item after the beginning of the grid, the column headers do not line up with the column data.  If I make the header section a button ion-item, they do match up.  Is there any way to get around this?  Or do I have to basically recreate the button style on the ion-row object?

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row align-items-start>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Work Order</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Line</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Job Code</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Vehicle</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-25 text-left no-border no-padding>Description</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Time</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Code</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>Repair Type</ion-col>
 </ion-row>



 <button ion-item no-margin *ngFor="let job of jobs" ngDefaultControl no-border no-padding>
  <ion-row align-items-start>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.wo}}</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.lineNumber}}</ion-col> 
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.vmrs_maj}} - {{job.vmrs_int}} - {{job.vmrs_min}}</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.vehicle}}</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-25 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.description}}</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.hoursWorked}}:{{job.minutesWorked}}</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.completionCode}}</ion-col>
   <ion-col width-10 text-left no-border no-padding>{{job.repairType}}</ion-col>

  </ion-row>
 </button>



</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ion grid is made up of 12 columns and you would use col-12 as attribute on column to make it span entire row.
You only have 12 columns to choose from
So you could have 2 col-6, 3 col-4, 4, col-3 6 col-2 12 col-1, or some combo like two columns in row col-4,  col-8 that would take up 1/3, 2/3 respectively. It's all covered [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid)